# Kotlin, generic addition

Tags: generics, math, kotlin

Is it possible to implement a generic, let's say, addition like the following:

```
public abstract interface NumberEx {

    abstract fun plus(other: NumberEx): NumberEx
}

abstract interface Vec2t<T : NumberEx> {

    open var x: T
    open var y: T

    fun add(res: Vec2t<T>, a: Vec2t<T>, bX: T, bY: T): Vec2t<T> {
        res.x = a.x + bX
        res.y = a.y + bY
        return res
    }
}
```

Because here the compilers complains about `a.x + bX` and `a.y + bY`:

> Type mismatch. Required: T   Found: NumberEx

Comment: I read "Kotlin, generic addiction" : <

Comment: It's ok, we all are kotlin addicted here. In b4 Kotlin Anonymous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to employ a recursive `NumberEx` definition like so:

```
interface NumberEx<T : NumberEx<T>> {
    operator fun plus(other: T): T
}
```

This would require an implementation to provide a plus operator:

```
class ANumber : NumberEx<ANumber> {
    override fun plus(other: ANumber): ANumber {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

And would make it type safe and understandable by compiler to use in `Vec2t`

```
interface Vec2t<T : NumberEx<T>> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more question, is there a way to get the primitive types (`Float`, `Int`, etc..) extending `NumberEx`?